# Как обработать завершение процесса во всех случаях?

Tags: python

Есть ли в Python 3.8 некая переопределяемая системная функция (или что-то схожее) ,которая вызывается при выходе из программы будь то Exeption или просто конец программы. И можно ли самому при выходе из ядра родительского процесса  перед самым концом запустить функцию которая выполнит мои инструкции.

Comment: Смотря какой выход. Если выход по вызову `sys.exit()`, то бросается исключение `SystemExit`, которое можно перехватить.

Comment: Родной питоновский модуль `atexit`  - там все есть для этого

Answer (score 1):

Недавно узнал о таком модуле как `atexit` из стандартного набора библиотек python. Использование элементарное:

```
import atexit


def my_any_func():
    print("bye-bye!")


atexit.register(my_any_func)
```

Мы всего лишь регистрируем функцию/функции которые хотим выполнить при завершении работы программы и они будут выполнены автоматически когда это произойдёт.

Ещё один вариант через блок `try-except-finaly`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    finally:
        my_any_func()
```

Хорошей практикой считается иметь точку входа в приложение, если при этом обернуть её в блок `try-except-finaly` получим что код в `finaly` будет обязательно вызываться когда основной скрипт завершит работу.

Ну и ещё один вариант вам подсказали в комментариях: использовать `sys.exit()` и отлавливать `SystemExit`, но как по мне это не так элегантно как первые два варианта.

Comment: Надо же, не знал о таком. Век учись.